# Angular2: fetching REST-data with ngOnInit vs Resolver

Tags: angular

I'm facing an angular2 software design problem and I don't know what's a better solution:

Fetching REST-data in ngOnInit or use a resolver?

I never ran into problems fetching data in the ngOnInit-method but now I've heard about resolvers and I'm not sure what to use:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authHttp.get('http://localhost:8080/configuration')
      .map((response: Response) => <ConfigurationData>response.json())
      .subscribe(settings => this.settings = settings);
}
```

**vs**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationsResolver implements Resolve<ConfigurationData> {
    constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ConfigurationData> {
        return this.authHttp.get('http://localhost:8080/configuration')
            .map((response: Response) => <ConfigurationData>response.json());
    }
}
```

Resolvers result in much more code. Extra classes, declare a provider and so on.

So what do you think? Any statements and best practice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service approach is cleaner in terms of single responsibility principle and testability.

Let's say one of your business layer components needs configuration. So its need can be expressed as "I need configuration". It doesn't care about how to get it, where to get it and all that - all it needs is configuration data, that's all. So, in order to get this data component now expresses another query - "I need someone who knows how to fetch configuration data for me". This is where you inject your service. Main component does not care if this data is hardcoded, fetched from server or somehow derived from random generator - it is not its business. So your main component does not maintain any logic not related to its tasks and your config fetcher does not maintain any logic about what to do with this data. Each of them has strictly one responsibility.

This allows for easy testing of them. You can easily mock config data fetcher component and inject it in you main component. It gives you easy way to test your main component in easily controllable conditions - your mocked component allows you to test how main thing handles fetching correct data, incorrect data, call failures, and so on - since it is your mock it can help you to simulate whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

using the resolver, the components inside the target component would be able to access the data fetched in the resolver; and that's not the case with nginit method .... you need to test it to confirm

Comment: and maybe the resolver technique is faster ... because it begin fetching data befor even initialising the component .....; once again you can confirm that using the dev tool

Answer (score 0):

Resolvers are executed before navigating to the route, then this way you can avoid showing an empty template if the rest service takes long to respond.

Answer (score -1):

The best way if you have enterprise app is to use [RxJs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), keep your logic in services and triggering services in router gourd or components.

Or something fancier and more code use [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) and keep all logic in the state.

Between this two choose you wrote, I would rather write everything in services and keep component cleaner.